# How to sign CSR in Azure key vault using a Issuer Certificate

Tags: azure, encryption, certificate, azure-keyvault

I have uploaded the issuer certificate in the azure key vault and now i want to send a CSR generated in my system to azure and get it signed by the Issuer certificate in the KV and return me back the signed certificate. Any idea on how to accomplish it?

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry that you are not able to accomplish it. For Azure Key Vault's usage scenario, you may refer to [What is Azure Key Vault?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-overview).

Just as explained in that article, for `Certificate`, Azure Key Vault lets you easily provision, manage, and deploy public and private Transport Layer Security/Secure Sockets Layer (TLS/SSL) certificates for use with Azure and your internal connected resources.

You can generate a new certificate from [Public CA (DigiCert or GlobalSign)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/kv/get-started-with-azure-key-vault-certificates#enroll-programmatically-from-public-ca-certificate-authority).

If you want to use custom CA, you can only create a CSR, and get your certificate from that CA, and finally update your certificate to Azure Key Vault. Refer to: [Create a certificate manually and get signed by a CA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/kv/get-started-with-azure-key-vault-certificates#create-a-certificate-manually-and-get-signed-by-a-ca)

Comment: Thank you Jack for the reference links. Will go through it for a solution. (y)

Comment: Like so many Azure services, Keyvault stops JUST short of being actually useful for something.